# How can I configure tag subscription email accounts?

Tags: support

I'm (mostly **) sure it's possible, because I've done it for certain tags. Where is the setting to change the email address for certain tag subscriptions? I want work related subscription topics to go to one email and private subscription topics to go to another email.

** Having multiple accounts and not realizing it has caused me great problems from my iPhone to other networks, so I can't rule out the possibility that I just have a different account presenting the illusion of this preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Kendra for your answer. Filters are evidently something different. After following your instructions, and finding same page I thought to check my emails. At the bottom of the emails was the link I needed.

For others, you can find this feature, click on the main StackExchange webpage --> user profile --> subscriptions --> manage (see image)

Thanks again.

[[image: Find subscription preferences here[1]]
[image: change the email for one tag subscription here]

UPDATE.
I found your link to that filter page very confusing in regards to my objective. Instead of seeing a **list of subscribed tags and their preferences** as I show in my first screen capture, this page shows a list of **posts *"based on [my] favorite tags"***.

What's more, *my* **posts *"based on [my] favorite tags"*** page features tags which I've not used in a dog's age--fedora-15!! (see the left red annotation highlighting three tags). None my recent subscribed tags are shown in *details*. Maybe I'm just using this feature incorrectly? Maybe it's a bug?

Scrolling down the *Edit Profile & Settings* page, past the *Manage filtered questions emails*, there is an even more hopeful link, *advanced tag subscriptions*, which takes me to the **favorites** page. Maybe this link should be fixed to point to tag subscriptions?

[image: filter settings]

Comment: Your method actually goes to the exact same feature as mine. But it's always good to see another way to get there. That said, it did not occur to me that your subscriptions did not automatically become filters. Useful to know.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Take a look at what I'm seeing in _my_ account. As I comment in my update, my first screen capture shows a list of my **subscribed tags and their preferences**. My third screen capture, following your link, takes me to a list of **posts** filtered on my tags. What's more, they're not the same tags! I have favorite tag subscription at Stack for `semantic-web`, `wordnet`, but it's not listed with `fedora-15`, `design-patterns`, `vim`, which are all tags I subscribed to many years ago.

Comment: Really, saying it's the same "feature" in my previous comment was incorrect. They are different _features_ (though very similar) but your second screenshot is the same _page_ as the filter feature. You can even see an option to turn the subscription _into_ a filter. Both cause emails to be sent to you, afaik. Likewise, "Favorite Tags" and "subscribed tags" aren't actually the same- Favorite Tags are those you've favorited on the site and affect the question list and can be used for searching. You can subscribe to a tag without favoriting it, and likewise favorite one without subscribing to it.

Comment: @Kendra said: *"Favorite Tags" and "subscribed tags" aren't actually the same* -- Then that is the distinction which makes all the difference (and likely explains why my new subscribed tags are not shown). And further adds to my belief "advanced tag subscriptions", should be linked to the *"subscriptions"*, rather than the *"favorites"* page results.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile, click the "Settings" tab if on Meta or the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab if on Main, and click "Preferences" on the left hand side.

[image: Preferences Option]

You'll see "Q&A Emails" in the right hand column. The far left of this portion will have the link "Manage filtered questions emails" which will take you to your filter settings.

[image: Manage Link]

When you set up a filter, you can set what email it goes to. You can set up multiple filters with different email accounts. You can also set up one filter for more than one tag, if you'd like to condense your filters.